# "Конкретное противопоказание, несовместимое с жизнью"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов

> И на самом деле он не был каким-то там алкоголиком. Не был
>   сумасшедшим. Просто пить ему было нельзя. Это вполне **конкретное
>   противопоказание, несовместимое с жизнью**. Контуженный. И ловушка на
>   тромбы стоит.

И что делать?

Вместо "противопоказание" - "показание"?

Точку после "противопоказание"? А далее "Несовместимо с жизнью"?

А что было задумано? спервоначалу-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Это вполне конкретное противопоказание, несовместимое с жизнью.

Так нельзя сказать и так не говорят. Это, в лучшем случае, стилистическая ошибка. Предложение не читается однозначно — его вообще нельзя прочесть правильно, я считаю. Я бы предложил такую минимальную правку:

> Просто пить ему было нельзя. Это было несовместимо с жизнью — вполне
>   конкретное противопоказание.

Answer (score 1):

"Несовместимое с жизнью" - заимствование из медицинского жаргона. В медицине это обычно о ранении, о состоянии какого-нибудь органа, но (как минимум авторски) можно распространить эту "несовместимость" и на напр. *поведение* больного. Поэтому в смысловом отношении у меня это предложение не вызывает вопросов,  а понимать его можно так, что для персонажа пить было "смерти подобно" (**смертельно опасно**, почти с гарантией убивало).

Comment: Там когнитивный диссонанс возникает в другом месте. Буквальное прочтение означает: рекомендация отказаться от алкоголя была несовместима с жизнью. В таком виде предложение нельзя оставить, я считаю.

Comment: Противопоказание (в отличие от "показаний" людей в суде и пр.) - реальное обстоятельство (здесь - опасность при употреблении), это не "рекомендация".

Answer (score 0):

Может: "Это **же** вполне конкретн**ая слабость**, несовместим**ая с нормальной** жизнью."?